# fileloadexception and strongly typed assembly is required

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add a view (Asp.Net MVC RC) with the "add view" right click menu and I'm getting a file load exception.
Is this a problem of ASP.NET MVC RC or some kind of configuration problem?
[Link to screenshot](http://www.shareimmage.com/images/134_error1.gif)

Comment: keep an eye on this thread:
http://forums.asp.net/p/1377554/2918770.aspx#2918770

I think a solution will pop up there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this thread:
[link text](http://forums.asp.net/p/1377554/2918770.aspx#2918770)

Phil Haack says you need to update the web.config in the views folder.  So I created a new project and copied that over to my existing project and it now works - no more FileLoadException.

Answer (score 1):

Did you uninstall older versions properly before you installed the RC?

Comment: yes, previous version was correcly uninstalled. Could that be linked to the fact that I use Win2003 instead of Xp as a development machine

Comment: it shouldn't matter if you're using 2003 or xp

Comment: I can't think of anything else from the error. Can you try uninstalling ASP.NET MVC and reinstall it again?